# Characters defined by cyclic extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a finite cyclic extension of degree $p$ over ${\bf Q}$. As I understand it, there is a way to associate a cyclic character to this extension. How does one do this explicitly? And how far can this be generalized to other extensions?

When $p=2$ we only have $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{D})$ and the character is the quadratic residue symbol $(\frac{D}{\cdot})$.

Comment: The cyclic character will be one of the non-trivial characters of the Galois group in this case, since it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$. I am not sure if this is what you mean though?

In general, you can take any representation of your Galois group, and then take the trace to obtain a character of the Galois group.

Comment: Thanks, I mean something more concrete: let's say I have a cubic cyclic extension $K$. What is the character that I can associate to $K$ that is analogous to the quadratic residue symbol? Is it just the cubic residue symbol?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is something like Artin reciprocity which holds for any abelian extension (ie galois with abelian galois group). Quadratic reciprocity can be derived from this

Comment: Ah. I see. I think I might have slightly misunderstood. I think maybe what you are looking for is the Artin symbol, which is part of the Artin Reciprocity that Matt B mentioned?

Comment: So the Artin symbol would map from the ideal classes prime to $p$, to the Galois group identified with $({\bf Z}/p{\bf Z})^\times$?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer at the same time to your question and that of @Sommer on "Galois group of extension generated by all cubic roots".

First the purely algebraic part. Let $p$ be an odd prime, $\mu_p$ the group of $p $-th roots of 1, $k$ a field of characteristic distinct from $p$. Let $K = k(\mu_p)$, $ \Delta = Gal(K/k)$, $F$ a cyclic extension of $k$. Then $E := F.K$ is abelian, and by Kummer theory, $L$ is obtained from $K$ by adding a $p$-th root of an element $ \alpha \in K^*$ . Let $G_K (p)$ be the Galois group of the maximal abelian extension of $K$ of exponent $p$, and $\mathcal K = K^* /(K^*)^p$. Still by Kummer theory, $ G_K (p) \cong Hom (\mathcal K, \mu_p)$, and $ \Delta = Gal(K/k)$ acts naturally on it. It is convenient to write $G_K (p)$ additively and to think of it as a vector space over the prime field $\mathbf F_p$. As a vector space, $G_K (p)$ is thus the dual space of $ \mathcal K $, but it is not so as a $\Delta$ - module, because $\Delta$ acts non trivially on $\mu_p$ (via the so called Teichmüller character). Let $<\alpha>$ be the subgroup generated by the class of $ \alpha$ modulo $(K^*)^p$.The abelianity of $E/k$ means that $ \Delta$ acts trivially by conjugation on $Gal(F/k)\cong Gal(E/K)\cong Hom (<alpha>, \mu_p)$, in other words, that $Gal(F/k)$ is a quotient of the co-invariants $ G_K (p)_{\Delta}$. In conclusion,$G_k (p) \cong Hom (\mathcal K, \mu_p)^{\Delta} = Hom(\mathcal K (-1)_{\Delta}, \mathbf F_p)$, or equivalently, $Hom (G_k (p),\mathbf F_p) \cong  \mathcal K (-1)_{\Delta}$. Here $M(-1)$ denotes the module $M$ with Galois action modified in such a way that $Hom (M(-1), \mathbf F_p) = Hom (M, \mu_p)$ ("Tate twist").

Then the arithmetic part, which could be complicated for a general number field, but here $ p = 3$, $k = \mathbf Q$, $K = k(\mu_3)$, and $\Delta$ is generated by « complex conjugation ». Since $p$ is odd, one can decompose any abelian $p$-group on which $\Delta$ acts into the direct sum of its « plus » and « minus » components. Thus, taking into account the Teichmuller character as noted above, we get $G_{\mathbf Q} (3) \cong Hom (\mathcal K,  \mu_3)^{+}$, or equivalently, $ Hom (G_{\mathbf Q} (3), \mathbf F_3) \cong \mathcal K^{-}$ . This seems huge, but it is not quite. We could determine $\mathcal K^{-}$ using the local-global principle for cubic powers in CFT, but it amounts to the same to apply directly the Kronecker-Weber theorem to determine $G_{\mathbf Q} (3)$. The K-W theorem asserts that the Galois group of the maximal abelian extension of $ \mathbf Q$ is isomorphic to the direct product of all the $l$-adic units $\mathbf Z_l^*$. But $\mathbf Z_l^* \cong \mathbf Z/(l -1)$ x $\mathbf Z_l $ (additive notation) if $l$ is odd, $\mathbf Z/(2)$ x $\mathbf Z_2$ if $l = 2$. It follows immediately that $ G_{\mathbf Q} (3)$ is the direct product of  $\mathbf Z/3$  by the $\mathbf Z/(l -1)$ mod3 for  $l$ congruent to 1 mod 3 . So the character group we are looking for  is described explicitly.